# How to return emacs to qwerty keyboard layout?

Tags: layout, emacs

I have changed Emacs input layout into Hebrew. Now, when I try to return it into English, I get the devorak layout and not the qwerty layout. I tried other layouts such as UTF-8 or ascii without any change. How do I return it then?

**Edit:**
I have used `C-x RET C-\` to change the layout

Comment: What method did you use to change it into Hebrew and back, to begin with? C-x RET C-\?

Comment: @Dolda2000 yes, I have used this method. I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching to another layout with `C-x RET C-\` actually enters a special mode wherein an alternate layout is active, and therefore the "normal" layout isn't available in that mode. Turn the mode off, instead, using just `C-\`. You should see the modeline changing.