# Keyboard layout sticks to french on emacs over ssh

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24

I have a mac, on which I routinely use two keyboard layouts, French and UK english. 
Locally I have an installation of Aquamacs I believe, which is running fine. However my work involves connecting to a ssh server running on a Linux x64 architecture, and this is where the problem lies.

When running emacs over ssh with X forwarding, the keyboard layout/input method remains French, no matter what I do. I have tried toggling input method, forcing it to British, I even tried other input methods that seemed to work fine. The French mac keyboard layout is very unpractical for programming, so I would really like to use the regular british layout.

I have tried recompiling the latest version of emacs from scratch, I have also moved my .emacs so that it is not used and removed .emacs.d, to no avail. I have also tried the solution here [How to return emacs to qwerty keyboard layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098082/how-to-return-emacs-to-qwerty-keyboard-layout) This just changes U into U+1 in the status bar (I do not know what that means) but has no effect on the layout.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I have tried toggling input method" is very vague,since there are many different levels where this can be done.

I suspect the issue is that your X server is using the French layout for some reason and that it does not correctly react to changes in Mac OS X's own layout choice.  You might like to check the config of your X server.

Comment: You're right it was vague. I meant I tried 'M-x toggle-input-method' and 'M-x set-input-method' from within emacs. But you were right, after checking that all X11 applications were concerned by this issue, I checked the 'Follow system keyboard layout' in the properties of my X11 client and the problem was solved. Thanks !